# How to extract the unique letters from two strings into a variable? Java

Tags: for-loop

I'm trying to Program Flames.. 
here's what i've done so far..

```
String name1,name2,uniqueletters;
int x,y;
Scanner zxc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the first name:");
name1 = zxc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the second name:");
name2 = zxc.nextLine();
name1 = name1.toUpperCase();
name2 = name2.toUpperCase();
for (x=0;x<name1.length();x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<name2.length();y++)
          {
          if(name1.charAt(x)==name2.charAt(y))
```

i do not know what to add anymore..
the output must be like this..

```
Enter the first name: Hello
Enter the second name: World
Unique letters: HEWRD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use single loops :

```
    String name1, name2, uniqueletters;
    int x;
    Scanner zxc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the first name:");
    name1 = zxc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the second name:");
    name2 = zxc.nextLine();
    name1 = name1.toUpperCase();
    name2 = name2.toUpperCase();
    uniqueletters = "";
    for (x = 0; x < name2.length(); x++) {

        if (name1.contains(String.valueOf(name2.charAt(x))) == false) {                
            uniqueletters += String.valueOf(name2.charAt(x));
        }
    }
    for (x = 0; x < name1.length(); x++) {
        if (name2.contains(String.valueOf(name1.charAt(x))) == false) {                
            uniqueletters += String.valueOf(name1.charAt(x));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(uniqueletters);
```

I haven't tested this though, i'm just writing off from your code directly

Comment: there's an error in the if statement,
The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)

Comment: yes, I didn't realize the conversion between chars and strings.  I just fixed it though and added line to output the result.  Please test it and if it works, mark this as an answer. thanks

Comment: no problem. thank you, too.  I'm new to SO, so it's big for me to have my first answer marked ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain it in the form of steps.

Step1: Create an array, say a1, of size 26 and initialise to 0.

Step2: Traverse string1 and for each character string1[i] assign value of 1 for that letter in the array a1. That is, a1[string1[i]-'a']=1;

Step3: Similarly, for second string, create an array a2 and initialise to 0.

Step4: Similar to step2 traverse string2 but for each character string2[i] assign value of -1 for that letter in the array a2. That is, a2[string2[i]-'a']=-1;

Step5: For each element in array a1, add the corresponding element in a2 from it. That is a1[i]=a1[i]+a2[i];

Step6: Traverse the array a1 and check for each element if it is 1 or -1. Each of these element correspond to the alphabet that is unique in either of the two strings. Therefore, print each of such corresponding letters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the teacher told us to compare the two strings letter by letter using for loop

Comment: then you should add it in your question. There are many ways to do this. Example with `ArrayList.contains` method.

Comment: Franz: Do your homework yourself. It helps you think beyond the usual method. The reason why I didn't write the code so that you can understand the algorithm while coding yourself. Not upvoting a legitimate answer was not expected.